# Where does 'clear' command come from?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm from windows background. I wish to know where do all commands like `exit`,`clear` comes from in my terminal?

And are they scripts? In what language they have been written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this depends:-) Some are internal commands of your shell, some scripts, some are compiled programs.

You can find out more with the `type` command: For example: `type type` gives (in my cygwin bash!) `type is a shell builtin`.

If you type `type bash`, your answer will be something like `bash is /usr/bin/bash`.

Now you can inspect what type of file /usr/bin/bash is: `file /usr/bin/bash` says  something like `... executable ...`, so this will be a compiled file, presumably written in C, FORTRAN or whatever. If the answer is something like `... script...`  you can inspect this file with a normal text editor like gedit, vim or whatever you like.

Answer (score 5):

Most of all , i can rather say ALMOST all commands came from UNIX , a Predecessor and fundamental mechanism Behind LINUX.

Most of the Utilities , like `mv- move` , `cp- copy` is a utility in Linux since they are utilize to do basic management functions.This holds true for every other such utilities , i would rather say Utilities providing Functionalities to integrate and make it as whole Principle Operation based OS kind of Entity.

Now coming to topic , these Commands or Utilities were mostly developed by [**GNU**](http://www.gnu.org/) called **Core GNU utilities** .

You will find most of the basic commands from Core Utilities description [**page**](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Introduction), said that , **Linux** is just a Name of **Kernel**, Whereas **Ubuntu** is an Entire Advanced Integrated OS of such utilities.

Commands are mostly written in C language , Shell is an Interpreter between kernel  and Commands. Bash being the Best of them.

About scripts , not entirely they are not , for scripting purpose Python & Perl are used ,accessible in bash.

**Note**: In Ubuntu you will find [Coreutils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/coreutils/) installed .

> This package contains the basic file, shell and text manipulation
>   utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system.
>
> Specifically, this package includes: arch base64 basename cat chcon
>   chgrp chmod chown chroot cksum comm cp csplit cut date dd df dir
>   dircolors dirname du echo env expand expr factor false flock fmt fold
>   groups head hostid id install join link ln logname ls md5sum mkdir
>   mkfifo mknod mktemp mv nice nl nohup nproc od paste pathchk pinky pr
>   printenv printf ptx pwd readlink rm rmdir runcon sha*sum seq shred
>   sleep sort split stat stty sum sync tac tail tee test timeout touch tr
>   true truncate tsort tty uname unexpand uniq unlink users vdir wc who
>   whoami yes

For inbuilt **Clear** command functionality  in Bash shell you can use **Ctrl+L**

Answer (score 0):

Some of them are part of the functionality of the interpreter you are working at(I presume you are using `bash`), but can be overridden with one that is not built-in(should such an executable exist) using `env`*`commmand`*. The rest of the important commands are in `/bin` or `/sbin`, which is on your path, giving quick access to these commands almost seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

They are usually written in C, but they might also be ba/sh, python, perl, ... scripts (such `adduser` being a perl wrapper to `useradd`). You can tell which scripting language they are written in by looking at the first line of the script itself or at the line which starts with `#!` (eg: `#!/usr/bin/perl`). This is of course not valid for compiled C commands.

They are located in /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin mainly and you can access them from anywhere (giving you the impression of being lower level commands) because they are in your PATH environmental variable.